# Computing sum with $\cot$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I want to compute terrible sum:
$$
z\cot z = \frac{z}{2^n}\left(\cot\frac{z}{2^n}-\tan\frac{z}{2^n} + \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}-1} \cot\left(\frac{z + k\pi}{2^n}\right) + \cot\left(\frac{z - k\pi}{2^n}\right)\right)
$$
Im trying use exponential form or expansion with Bernoulli numbers, but it's give me no benefits..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  A simple trick to prove your identity is just to compute the residues of both the LHS and the RHS at $z=\pm\pi,\pm 2\pi,\pm 3\pi,\ldots$ and check that they match.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shown your own work on this identity, I can only give you a hint:  use induction on $n$, starting with the trivial case $n = 1$.  There is a double-angle identity that you can exploit that naturally completes the induction step from $n$ to $n+1$.